# How do you finish resolving merge conflicts for a rebasing pull in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, merge-conflict-resolution

When I do a `git pull --rebase`, and there are merge conflicts in my commits, I get the conflict diff view, resolve all the conflicts and stage the files, then what?

I can open a terminal and run `git rebase --continue` but shouldn't there be a button inside VS Code somewhere to finish the rebase?

Comment: Related: [Git merge conflicts - "commit" VS "rebase --continue"](/q/22017013/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the commit button / action. When you're doing a rebase, the commit button will do `git rebase --continue` instead of `git commit` ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/6614#issuecomment-426163072)).