Cant Resolve Merge Conflicts in VSCode in a Submodule
Problem
If a Merge Conflict occurs in a Submodule in VSCode the Merge editor opens and i can resolve the conflict, after that i can commit those changes.

But after that i cant click on continue or something else i have to go to the directory and execute
git rebase --continue

after that all seems to work.
To my Question
Do i make something wrong or is there a configuration i miss?
VSCode
Try to alter the configuration settings in VSCode for merge conflicts

Once you resolve your errors you have to add them back to the staging area and committing them.

In VSCode - use the commit input box.
There isn't any "button" for git rebase --continue

Solution described here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/6614


P.S.
To "avoid" resolving same conflicts in the future setup git rerere
git rerere

The name stands for "Reuse Recorded Resolution".

All you need to do is to set the git config flag :-)
# enabled the option to record the conflicts resolutions
git config --global rerere.enabled true


If you prefer rerere to auto-stage files it can resolve, add this second configuration:
# Enabled the option to stage resolved conflicts 
git config --global rerere.enabled true




I don´t understand your answer sry. So my Problem is that i do this:
Have a merge conflict -> resolve it in merge conflict editor -> commit my changes and than i cant do anything else (Repo is checkout at some random branch b9827jje)
So what do i have to do ?

You need to add resolve message in the commit box
You should not work on the submodule code inside your main repository, it usually checkout as Detached HEAD.
Did you made changes on the main repo submodule folder?

Yes i add reolve messages after that i get the picture above. I made changes in a submodule insed a main repository. My submodules file looks like this:
[submodule "src/visualizer"]
path = src/visualizer
url = 
ignore = dirty

That not recommended to do it inside the main repo. now you need to commit changes, checkout new branch and take it from there

So i cant resolve merge conflicts in vscode inside a Submdoule via the Merge Editor ?

you can but its not that straight forward

re: "There isn't any "button" for git rebase --continue" - interesting... https://stackoverflow.com/a/75655745/11107541

See the attached image, its the PR from the vscode :-) you need to do it with commit
